# Neighborhood of $0$ is absorbent in topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Consider a topological vector space $(X,\tau_X)$ and $N_0$ a neighborhood of $0$. I want to show, that it is absorbent, i.e. $X=\cup_{t> 0} tN_0$.

My idea would be to take an arbitrary $x_0\in X$ and to find a $\delta > 0$, such that $\delta x_0\in \operatorname{int} N_0$. Then, you could see, that $x_0\in\delta^{-1} N_0$.

However, I do not exactly know, why there is this $\delta$, such that $\delta x_0\in N_0$. My impression is, that otherwise $0$ must be a boundary point of $N_0$ ? Which would be a contradiction to the fact, that $N_0$ is a neighborhood of $0$?

I know, that the scalarmultiplication $s_\delta:X\rightarrow X$, $s_\delta(y):=\delta y$ is continuous, but I am not sure how to use this fact here, because of the following:

By definition, a function $f$ is continuous in point $x$, if for any $N$, a neighborhood of $f(x)$, there is a $M$, a neighborhood of $x$, such that $f(M)\subseteq N$.

To use this definition, wouldn't I need to use the scalar multiplication $s_0:X\rightarrow X$, $s_0(y)=0$? (For mapping a neighborhood of $x_0$ into $N_0$, a neighborhood of $0=s_0(x_0)$?)

Any help or hint is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: This indeed comes down to the fact that scalar multiplication is continuous. Consider an element $x\in X$, then by continuity of scalar multiplication and the fact that $\lim\limits_{t\to0}tx=0$, there exists a $t_0\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $t_0 v\in N_0.$

Comment: Oh, you mean I have to look at the map $f_{x_0}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X$, $f_{x_0}(t)=tx_{0}$? Because what you write is basically my question, since I do not necessarily have a metric on the TVS, right? Meaning, the notion of limit is again defined via neighborhoods.

Comment: The fact that there is no metric does not cause any problems, this is just a topological property. To unpack the limit, we know that for each open $0\in U\subset X$ there exists a $t_0\in \mathbf{R}_{>0}$ such that $tx\in U$ for all $0<t<t_0.$ This is what continuity means, so if we pick $U=N_0$ you get the desired result.

Comment: I think I got confused with the topology on the product space. I just posted an answer. It would be nice, if you could comment on that, if it's right. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of a TVS, the map $$m:\mathbb{R}\times X\rightarrow X,\quad  (t,x)\mapsto tx$$ is continuous. Pick $x_0\in X$. For an open set $U\subseteq X$, which contains $0$, the set $m^{-1}(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times X$ is open and contains $(0,x_0)$. Since $$\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}\times X}=\{B_1\times B_2:B_1\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}, B_2\in\mathcal{B}_{X}\}$$ is a basis of the topology on $\mathbb{R}\times X$, there must be $\epsilon >0$ and an open $B_X\subseteq X$, such that $$(0,x_0)\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times B_X\subseteq m^{-1}(U).$$
From this, one finds, that for any $\delta\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\backslash\{0\}$, it holds $\delta x_0=m(\delta,x_0)\in U$, such that $$x_0\in \delta^{-1}U\subseteq\cup_{t>0}tU.$$

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: +1. It is important that $m$ is continuous, which is a stronger condition than that $f_k(x)=kx$ is continuous from $X $to $X$ for each scalar $k$.